Has British English always had two alternative pronunciations of "been"?
The OALD gives the following pronunciations for been (verb):

/biːn/,  /bɪn/ (British)

/bɪn/ (American)


Do American English speakers think the two lines below rhyme?

Pussy cat, pussy cat, where have you been?
I've been to London to visit/look at/see the Queen.

Perhaps Brits have acquired the short vowel version from American influence.
EDIT:  This is a comparative/historical linguistics question; not the same as the question suggested as a duplicate.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Could you please explain exactly what question remains unanswered? The one in your title clearly has been answered (yes, both strong and weak forms have always existed in Modern English), and anything else is just a survey question ("Do Americans feel....?"), which we don't do.

Yes always, ever since Early Modern English
The answer is yes, British English has “always” (since Early Modern English) had a shortened vowel in the weak form of been. This is therefore nothing new.
The paywalled OED says that the original Middle English strong form of been with a long vowel (now a homophone of bean) developed a weak form with a shortened vowel (homophone of bin) during Early Modern English. It also notes that in American English a less reduced form (here a homophone of Ben) appeared without the full reduction.

The past participle (late Old English ge-bēon, early Middle English i-bēn) in later Middle English normally shows the expected retention of the prefix in the south (i-bē), and retention of final n in the north and midlands (bēn). The standard form been derives from the latter, and, in unstressed position, develops a weak pronunciation with shortened vowel in early modern English (continued as /bɪn/ and, in a less reduced form, as U.S. English /bɛn/).

And this reduction is not constant, either. There are many variations, which I detail further below. About this variability the late Prof. Lawler wrote in a comment some years ago:

Not only that, but individuals vary in how tense the vowel is, and how long it's held, often producing different pronunciations under different conditions (time of day, stress level, tiredness, irritation, etc.). So whatever it says in the dictionary, just treat that as a conductor's A; everybody varies from it in practice.

What we say: Ben and bean, bin and bun
Any of these enumerated below with numbered phonetics is possible in America, including from the
same speaker depending on whether we’re talking a strong form or a weak
form:

[bɛn]
[biːn]
[bijn]
[bijən]
[bɪn]
[bɪjən]
[bɨn]
[bən]
[bn̩]

Strong forms: Ben and bean
When stressed, a comparatively rare occurrence, been is most commonly
a homophone of Ben in America.  Those with the pin–pen merger may
pronounce it as a homophone of bin even in its strong form, even though
normally bin is only possible as a weak form. So their Ben becomes
bin there.
However, in some American dialects it can also be a homophone of bean.
And in emphatic form in the dialects that do have that long drawn-own
bean form, the diphthong may be broken with pre-nasal breaking and the
introduction of a schwa, making it sound almost like it has two syllables.
Weak forms: bin and bun
However, in its normal weak form, been is simply a homophone for bin,
and often even less than that, so much so that it might even sound like
bun to some listeners.  Look at the last three pronunciations given for
how that word reduces where it gets a schwa or syllabic n instead.
The strong forms can, do, and indeed must reduce to many of the other forms
listed above, and you should not consider those different. If you do not
reduce them, you will sound like a foreigner.
Where and when
The drawn-out form is most commonly found in the dialects of Southern White
American English. These are dialects retained contact with Britain longer, or
in a few cases, were more isolated and had less exposure to change.
There are fewer of these bean speakers than there of Ben speakers.
It’s a marked pronunciation to use bean here, but it does happen in some dialects. The bin speakers are just using weak forms. Probably.

Regardless of what happens in back-woods Appalachia et al, AmE just doesn't use bean. I have never heard it, except maybe in a song and I have heard a lot of AmE. Even the way some Pennsylvanians use "anymore" differently than other AmE speakers.  I wonder if you haven't wandered off into being territory.

If you really want to be technical, nasal  assimilation of place affects that /n/, as in He's bee[ŋ] gone or He's bee[m] promoted or He's bee[ɱ] found.

Is /bεn/ really the most common strong form? I don’t have /bεn/ as a possible variety at all, and I’ve always found it rather jarring, which means I tend to actively notice when I hear it… and in my anecdotal experience, strong /bɪn/ (which is what I have – and no, I don’t have the pin–pen merger) is far more common. (Incidentally, there is at least one common phrase where been is strong: “been there, done that”.)

@JanusBahsJacquet I can only have /bεn/  not /bɪn/ for the strong form, like in That’s not something he’s even ever BEEN! It's likewise “/bεn/  there done that” for me; “/bɪn/  there” is weird: it would be jarring for me to hear my weak  /bɪn/  there. It sounds southern or something. Certainly /bεn/ is the normal strong form in the American Midwest and the Great Lakes states, especially if for some reason you take Wiktionary to know what they're talking about demographically. But it takes money and time to do a real study on that.

Huh. I use both /bεn/ and /bɪn/ interchangeably as strong forms; when I try saying different sentences with stressed been I seem to choose more or less randomly.

@JanusBahsJacquet I've been looking into it, and you may well be right that /bɪn/ is "more common" than /bεn/ in the stressed form in America, albeit not crushingly so. The problem with ascertaining a general assessment not via scientifically sound surveys but merely through anecdotal samplings of youtube and the like is that prevalence may depend on region and register, and not all regions are equally well represented within the American media, which is now coastally not centrally dominated. I'll nonetheless later today try to edit what I wrote into better shape to reflect your observations.

The pronunciation of "been" as the same as "bean" isn't exclusive to British English. It can also be found in Australian English, Canadian English, South African English, and in the Englishes of other British Commonwealth countries. The "bean" pronunciation of "been" might have existed in American English too, particularly in the 'Transatlantic' accent (a pseudo British accent people in radio and movies used to put on in order to sound posh), which shares characteristics with the British 'received pronunciation' accent.
And it's not just "been" that has several pronunciations in Commonwealth English that so far as I know, aren't really present in American English. A few examples include some words that start with "pro", most notably "process", "progress" and "project". In these words, the O can be pronounced like that in the word " lot" (just like in American English) or the 'O' can have the same pronunciation as in "motion". "Again" can be pronounced as "a-ghen" or "a-gane".
